# Notation: Is the notation $\sim$ used for "equal in distribution"?

Tags: probability-theory, notation

According to wikipedia, and the usage among some math SE results of "equal in distribution" search, to write that 2 random variables $X$ and $Y$ are [equal in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equality_in_distribution) one writes as $X\overset{d}{=} Y$. I thought based on my lectures [and this notes (in page 107)](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/2docuat2016/probabilidades_y_estadistica_M/apunte2.pdf), and [exercise 4 of this problem set](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/2docuat2016/probabilidades_y_estadistica_M/practica3.pdf), that this way is also valid: $X \sim Y$. Is this used in some books, or has some acceptance somewhere you can refer to me?

Answer (score 4):

I have never seen people write 
$
X\sim Y
$ for "$X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution". The notation $P^X=P^Y$ is used in Jacod and Protter's *Probability Essentials*.

On the other hand, in probability theory, the symbol "$\sim$" is usually used in this format:
$$
X\sim \textrm{"some distribution"}.
$$

For instance, it is usually written that 
$
{\displaystyle X\sim{\mathcal {N}}(\mu ,\,\sigma ^{2})},
$
where  ${\mathcal {N}}(\mu ,\,\sigma ^{2})$ denotes the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Notation).

Similarly, one writes $X\sim Poi(\lambda)$ for Poisson distribution, and $X\sim B(n,p)$ for binomial distribution.

Comment: Is it also used for other famous well known distributions, like geometric, binomial, multinomial, poisson?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Normal distribution is an example.

Comment: In statistics, I have seen $X \overset{H_0}{\sim}Y$ for "$X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution under the null hypothesis $H_0$".

Answer (score 0):

Although one can understand what this implies, it is not a usual notation for equality in distribution and I have not seen that in a textbook before.

"$\sim$" as in $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is usually used when a random variable has a "classic" distribution that is well known and can be represented by an abbreviation as well as the corresponding parameters.

Answer (score -1):

In geometry, '$\sim$' has a fairly fixed (standard) meaning, namely "is similar to."

In other fields of math the usage of this symbol varies widely and it doesn't generally have a standardized or a fixed meaning—unless you count that it is *usually* used to indicate a binary operator of some sort.  (A binary operator is one that accepts two operands.)

In fact, I've generally seen $\sim$ used as the symbol of first resort when one wants to define one's own binary operator.

It may also refer to equivalence classes; in other words $A \sim B$ may be commonly used to signify that $A$ and $B$ belong to the same equivalence class.

Actually, the geometric meaning "is similar to" is an instance of this last definition, since similar geometric figures form an equivalence class; that is, any geometric figure is similar to itself, and if a geometric figure is similar to each of two others, those others are also similar to each other.

If I were to use this symbol in a paper and assign it a new meaning, I would probably use it to signify an equivalence class.  It *could* be assigned other meanings, though.